# Proof without words for Stirling formula

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, intuition, stirling-numbers, proof-without-words

It it easy to prove $$x^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}S(n,i)x_{(i)}$$
by induction or recursive formula...

But is there some proof without word for it? or at least a direct proof that concern with partitions of sets? or is there **any** intuition behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an intuition. You know that $x_{(i)}=\frac{x!}{(x-i)!},$ if you multiply and divide by $i!$ you get this expression
$$x^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}S(n,i)i!\frac{x!}{(x-i)!i!}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}S(n,i)i!\binom{x}{i},$$
You can think in why $S(n,i)i!$ represents surjective functions from $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}$ to $[i]=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}.$

So, basically, you are taking functions $f:[n]\longrightarrow[x]$ which are in the set $[x]^{[n]}$(s.t $|[x]^{[n]}|=x^n$) and seeing what's the cardinality of the image. If the cardinality is $i$, those functions can be represented in $S(n,i)i!\binom{x}{i}$.

Comment: You might want to add that for a fixed $n$ this combinatorial argument shows that the two $n$-th degree rational polynomials in $x$ agree at all $x\in\Bbb N$, so they must be identically equal.